# Multiply each element of a csr matrix column in Scipy

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

How can i multiply a particular column of a csr matrix with a fixed value (e.g. 5)
My approach seems not to work. First i'm creating a update_vector of the same size as my matrix column filled with my default value. Then i utilize the multiply-method of the Scipy csr matrix:

```
_column = _matrix.getcol(_index)
update_vector = numpy.tile(5, (_column.shape[0], 1))
_matrix[:, _index].multiply(update_vector)
```

The code runs without exception but the matrix stays unchanged. Do i have to create a copy first or is there another possibility to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `,multiply` is not an inplace operation.  It returns a new matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low level way of doing this operation in-place is something like:

```
_matrix.data[_matrix.indices == _index] *= 5
```

I would be surprised if you could not simply do:

```
_matrix[:, _index] *= 5
```

although it is hard to know if this really happens in place or triggers some form of copy without looking at the source code.

Comment: It must be an inplace operation, because `M.data.__array_interface__['data']` does not change.  Still the sparse `*=` is nowhere as fast as the equivalent dense operation.